# During Clone, change first column index of a multi-dim array for each input

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change the first column of a multi-dimensional array when I clone the section, with as little code as possible, I know I can individually go in and find each input, but that seems inefficient. So if I have for example;

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="height[0][]" />
    <input type="text" name="width[0][]" />
    <input type="text" name="depth[0][]" />
    <input type="text" name="weight[0][]" />
</div>
```

Once cloned and edited the cloned output should look like;

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="height[1][]" />
    <input type="text" name="width[1][]" />
    <input type="text" name="depth[1][]" />
    <input type="text" name="weight[1][]" />
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you clone the div?

Comment: Most likely with `$(".wrapper").clone(true)` @Eddie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` and `replace` (little bit fiddly):

```js
var newElems = $(".wrapper").clone(true).find("input").map((index, item) => {
  item.name = item.name.replace(/\[(\d)\]/, `[${parseInt($(item).attr("name").match(/\w+\[(\d)\]/)[1]) + 1}]`);
  return item;
});

console.log([...newElems]);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" name="height[0][]" />
  <input type="text" name="width[0][]" />
  <input type="text" name="depth[0][]" />
  <input type="text" name="weight[0][]" />
</div>
```

Comment: That works if I wanted to just add 1 to the first column, I am assuming if I had an variable instead of + 1, It would come back as that variable, will this also save to the clone for output? or just the variable newElems?

Comment: Also when  I use backticks, I get a type error, any idea why?